# Athena SQL - Self-join subquery using outer column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, inner-join, amazon-athena, presto

So I have catalogued data in an S3 bucket which very similarly resembles this data here:

```
+-----+-----------+---------+-----------------------+
| id  | title     | event   | time                  |
+-----+-----------+---------+-----------------------+
|1    | book A    | BORROW  | 2018-07-01 09:00:00   |
|1    | book A    | RETURN  | 2018-08-01 09:00:00   |
|2    | book B    | BORROW  | 2018-08-01 13:00:00   |
|2    | book B    | RETURN  | 2018-10-01 17:00:00   |
|1    | book A    | BORROW  | 2018-11-01 09:00:00   |
|1    | book A    | RETURN  | 2018-12-01 09:00:00   |
+-----+-----------+---------------------------------+
```

I basically want to be able to write a SELECT statement in Amazon Athena which displays the borrow and return times next to one another in a row like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| id  | title     | borrow_time           | return_time           |
+-----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1    | book A    | 2018-07-01 09:00:00   | 2018-08-01 09:00:00   |
|2    | book B    | 2018-08-01 13:00:00   | 2018-10-01 17:00:00   |
|1    | book A    | 2018-11-01 09:00:00   | 2018-12-01 09:00:00   |
+-----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

I've been spending heaps of time writing around 5 different queries (using things like `OUTER APPLY`, but Athena seems to be really sensitive to work with, especially considering that it doesn't have any functionality with `OUTER APPLY`. This is the logic for my latest statement:

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.title,
       b.time AS borrow_time,
       MIN(r.time) AS return_time
FROM (
      SELECT id,
             title,
             time
      FROM books
      WHERE event = 'BORROW'
     ) b
OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT id,
                   time
            FROM books
            WHERE event = 'RETURN'
           ) r
        ON b.id = r.id
       AND b.time < r.time
GROUP BY b.id,
         b.title,
         borrow_time
ORDER BY borrow_time;
```

Any ideas to get around this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the borrows and returns are all paired, you can enumerate them and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, title,
       max(case when event = 'BORROW' then b.time end) as borrow_time,
       max(case when event = 'RETURN' then b.time end) as return_time
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by b.id, b.event order by b.time) as sequm
      from books b
     ) b
group by id, title, seqnum
order by id, title, seqnum;
```

Comment: You've answered my prayers, this worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try with CASE WHEN and row_number() function :

```
with pcte as 
(
 SELECT id,
           title,event,time, row_number() over(order by id,title,event) as rn
           FROM books
)
    SELECT id,
           title,
           case when event = 'BORROW' then b.time end AS borrow_time,
           case when event = 'RETURN' then b.time end AS return_time
     FROM pcte order by id, title, rn
```